# What is the fastest way to find partial string in arrays with filter using lodash?

Tags: javascript, node.js, filter, lodash, reduce

Is there any way to find a partial string in an array more quickly than I have below?

Here is my example data:

```
const products = [
  {
    "product": "test1",
    "price": 11
  },
  {
    "product": "test2",
    "price": 31
  },
  {
    "product": "xxxx",
    "price": 21
  },
  {
    "product": "ssss",
    "price": 22
  },
]
```

Here are my keywords (but in reality, there are a **lot** more):

```
const keywords = [ "test", "xx" ]
```

I want to filter products with keywords then sum all product price my output should be

```
63
```

Here is what I tried to do: I filter my products first, I'm using `indexOf` because it faster than `includes`:

```
const fil = _.filter(products, (product) => {
    return _.some(keywords, (v) => product.name.indexOf(v) >= 0 );
});
```

then I sum them using `reduce`:

```
const sum = fil.reduce(function (sum, data) {
    return sum + data.price;
}, 0);
```

Everything works well but if I have to work with around 300k elements and 100k keywords, it takes around 3 min to find this query. Is there any way to decrease that time? (The `product` values are very unique, there aren't a lot of duplicates.)

Comment: Do you have a lot of *keywords*, or just a small number (as in the question)?

Comment: a lot of keywords too

Comment: So about 300k elements in the data array, how many (ish) in the keywords array?

Comment: around 1000 keywords @T.J.Crowder

Comment: I think the problem is in ._filter and ._some it take time too much more than I think even I try to use  indexOf instead of includes

Comment: Can you try to add more keywords up to 100k it will take 1 min +

Comment: I've been playing with it, and I'm afraid I don't see a way to speed it up. Not saying there isn't one, but I haven't found it in the time I've had to look. :-| (And yes, I'll try 1,000 keywords. I was working with the information you'd provided, so a lot fewer keywords than that.)

Comment: Oh, hey, here's a question: How unique are the `product` strings? Very unique? Not very unique?

Comment: its' very unique

Comment: Do you need the list of filtered products? Or just the sum?

Comment: just only sum price

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've said you only need the sum, not the list of filtered products, so we can reduce that time *slightly*, but probably not by a lot, by:

1. Reducing the amount of memory churn by not producing an array we don't need
2. Not making two passes through `products` when we only need one.
3. Avoiding function calls (although function calls are ***fast*** in JavaScript engines)

So:

```
let sum = 0;
for (const {product, price} of products) {
    for (const keyword of keywords) {
        if (product.includes(keyword)) {
            sum += price;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

That uses the new(ish) `for-of` loop. Under the covers, though, `for-of` involves function calls and creating objects (although when looping through a native array, the JavaScript engine may be able to optimize those away entirely). You might want to try it against a classic `for` loop to see which gives you the best speed:

```
let sum = 0;
let productsLength = products.length;
let keywordsLength = keywords.length;
let pIndex, kIndex;
for (pIndex = 0; pIndex < productsLength; ++pIndex) {
    const {product, price} = products[pIndex];
    for (kIndex = 0; kIndex < keywordsLength; ++kIndex) {
        if (product.includes(keywords[kIndex])) {
            sum += price;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Similarly, experiment with putting the loop variables *inside* the `for (...)` part vs. having them outside as above, but I'd tend to think outside would be just that tiny bit faster (because of how `let` works in `for` loops).

And finally, you might compare that against using the native (not lodash) `forEach` and `some` methods rather than `for` loops.

Comment: *(I don't normally post-and-run, but I have to disappear for the evening. I'll check back later if I need to clarify anything.)*

Comment: I will try and let you know my result later thank you very much

Comment: I've tried all process with 200k data and 100k keywords here is
 result ,  _.filter ->Processing time: 54.039s, for of -> Processing time:  1:16.528 (m:ss.mmm), for (pIndex ) -> Processing time 1:13.171 (m:ss.mmm)

Comment: I've change a little bit in if condition I used  product.name.indexOf(keyword) >= 0
here is my both result  for of-> Processing time 55.612s , for (pIndex  its around 53.700s ) 
I seems like the last method(pIndex)and  filter method are very very close

Comment: @newdev - Yeah, `_.filter` (and the native `filter`) will be basically `for` loops under the covers.

Comment: what if I change product into object key { test1: { product: test1, price: 5 }} something like this and find by key then sum is it possible ?

Comment: @newdev - It's certainly possible to do that but I don't think it'll make it any faster.