# How to sum all Object using index with an arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary, object, lodash

how can I search duplicate data using index key object here is my object :

```
 const obj = {
        product1: { name: 'paper', price: 4 },
        product2: { name: 'ball', price: 2 },
        product3: { name: 'ice-cream', price: 9 }
        product1: { name: 'paper', price: 2 }
    }
```

and I have an arrays

```
const arr = ["product1", "product2" ]
```

I want to get only product1 and product2 data then sum price together my output shold look like this `4+2+2 = 8`

Here is what I try to do

```
const newArr = _.map(arr, (name:string) => {
    return obj[name]
})

then I sum 

    const sum = newArr.reduce((data, obj)=> data + obj.price, 0);
```

the problem is in _.map when I map data if I return like this it will get only 1 product1 I want to get all of product name in `arr`

**### UPDATE ####**

I changed my object to unique but I still want to use arr to find some word not sure Can I use includes or indexOf in and Objects?

```
 const obj = {
        "product1 Hello": { name: 'paper', price: 4 },
        "product2 test": { name: 'ball', price: 2 },
        "product3 Hello3": { name: 'ice-cream', price: 9 }
        "product1 Hello4": { name: 'paper', price: 2 }
    }
```

Comment: yes please @cmgchess

Comment: yes I am , but as @RaiBnod said I will update my question in 1 min to clarigy things

Comment: can you update the expected o/p - from the e.g. you mentioned

Comment: I update question , I changed my obj  index to unique

Comment: the reason that I want to do this way because I want to optimize speed run time process  according to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71084180/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-find-partial-string-in-arrays-with-filter-using-lodas/71084691?noredirect=1#comment125672311_71084691 
I try to map products into object key then sum it

Comment: Are you structuring this data, or is this the way the data is structured that you need to work with?

Comment: You may have made the keys unique, but now you are not gaining anything from using this method as your goal was a "speed" increase and now you'll have to iterate through all the keys anyhow.

Comment: I already updated my keys to be unique is it possible to find key with some partial string ? @Brettski

Comment: No it is not possible to find the key on a partial string. I strongly believe you are going at this in the wrong direction.

Comment: @newdev i did a non lodash implementation maybe if u want I can try a lodash one as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non lodash implementation. filtered the array and ran reduce

```js
const arr = ["product1", "product2" ]
const obj2 = {
        "product1 Hello": { name: 'paper', price: 4 },
        "product2 test": { name: 'ball', price: 2 },
        "product3 Hello3": { name: 'ice-cream', price: 9 },
        "product1 Hello4": { name: 'paper', price: 2 }
    }
    
 let filtered = Object.entries(obj2).filter((el) => arr.includes(el[0].split(" ")[0]))
 
 const sum = filtered.reduce((acc,curr)=> acc + curr[1].price, 0);
 console.log(sum)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to iterate through the array and return a single value that is the total price.

```
    const products = {
        id1: { name: "paper", price: 4 },
        id2: { name: "ball", price: 2 },
        id3: { name: "ice-cream", price: 9 },
    };

    const productIds = ["id1", "id2"];

    const totalPrice = productIds.reduce((sum, id) => {
        return sum + products[id].price;
    }, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the `obj` will never contain the key `product1` twice. When that object is created during runtime the last value of `product1` is what is stored in the object. Even if you had a JSON object with those two keys, when you go to parse it, the last key will be the value. The only way I can think to do what you want is that you need to change the data prior to the object being created.

You added to unique keys, which isn't going to help you as now you'll need to iterate through all the keys to make sure you are getting all of them. You are better off putting the key in the object, and use an array of objects.

```js
const obj = [
  {key: 'product1', name: 'paper', price: 4},
  {key: 'product2', name: 'ball', price: 2},
  {key: 'product3', name: 'ice-cream', price: 9},
  {key: 'product1', name: 'paper', price: 2},
]
```

You can then use Array.reduce to combine the values, or other methods.

Now to get only product 1 and 2 use filter:

````js
const desiredProducts = obj.filter(p => ['product1','product2'].includes(p.key));
``

Or you can combine any matching keys using Array.reduce()

```js
const combinedResult = obj.reduce((cur, acc) => {
  const s = cur.find(c => c.key === acc.key);
  if (s)
    s.price += acc.price;
  else
   cur.push(acc);  

}, []);
````

Comment: thanks for answer I update my question I changed it into unique key

Answer (score 0):

JSON object can't hold duplicate keys. If so, it gets replaced by the last record.

In your case, the input becomes:

```
const obj = {
  product1: { name: 'paper', price: 2 },
  product2: { name: 'ball', price: 2 },
  product3: { name: 'ice-cream', price: 9 }
}
```

Your possible input will be like thes:

```
const obj = {
  product1: [{ name: 'paper', price: 4 }, { name: 'paper', price: 2 }],
  product2: [{ name: 'ball', price: 2 }],
  product3: [{ name: 'ice-cream', price: 9 }]
}
```

```
const obj = [
  {key: 'product1', name: 'paper', price: 4},
  {key: 'product2', name: 'ball', price: 2},
  {key: 'product3', name: 'ice-cream', price: 9},
  {key: 'product1', name: 'paper', price: 2},
]
```

#### Updated answer as updated code:

```
const obj = {
  "product1 Hello": {name: 'paper', price: 4},
  "product2 test": {name: 'ball', price: 2},
  "product3 Hello3": {name: 'ice-cream', price: 9},
  "product1 Hello4": {name: 'paper', price: 2}
}
const arr = ["product1", "product2"]

let keys = Object.keys(obj).filter(x => arr.some(y => x.includes(y)))
keys.map(x => obj[x].price).reduce((x, y) => x + y, 0)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer I update my question I add some string in to my obj so It's  already unique now

Comment: See the update on my answer.

Comment: please check my new obj update in my question not sure is it possible or not

Comment: See that above code!